# Is there 'projections' in Spring Data Rest for paremeters?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Projections in SDR is great for controlling your json output. But what about the input, the parameters into the REST call?

When I implemented my own controllers, I was able to approach a custom 'projection' for an input (create/update) by either

1. Creating custom DTO that is not the same as the full entity
2. or I could just use @JsonView and omit certain fields on the way in

Neither approach would work for SDR because you don't write the controllers. What is the way to do this?

Comment: I have a bad feeling that this is a XY problem. What is the original issue? Why do you need this feature?

Comment: What do you mean? Let's say I only want to allow the client to update 3 of the 5 fields of an entity. How do you indicate that in SDR?

Comment: Add `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)` to the other two fields, and deny PUT requests. So when the client sends PATCH requests, those 2 fields will be ignored

Comment: It’s not a read only field. You can write to it on create but not update.

Comment: In this case the solution a but more messy, but still easier than creating a 'projection'. I will add an answer soon

Answer (score 0):

Reflecting to the problem discussed in the comment section:

Add a `@Postload` method to the entity:

```
@PostLoad
public void postLoad() {
    ... store the values of the un-updateable fields into transient fields with @JsonIgnore
}

@JsonIgnore
@Transient
private String originalValue1;

@JsonIgnore
@Transient
private String originalValue2;
```

Create a `@HandleBeforeSave` event-handler. It's called during update, but not during create.

Copy the stored values to the original field in this handler.

- During creation the event-handler won't be called, all the fields can be set via the standard SDR endpoint.
- During update you override the changed values with their original value *before the save*, so when the entity is saved it will keep the original values.

Comment: I guess that works but that's one hell of an ugly hack. For one, this creates unnecessary performance hit for reading values before writes. Why cant SDR allow you specify what you accept?

Comment: I have a bad news for you: SDR always reads values before writes :)

Comment: Ok fair enough, but on a serious note. Is there really no way to do this? I suppose you can override specific REST call in a custom controller (like update) and make that accept a DTO?